# toggleClass React js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm building a web app with react js. I have CSS set to that when a user selects a div it highlights and when clicked again, it deselects. This is the code I have in jquery (but it needs to be written in react).

```
$("#select-reward-cards .card").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    selectRewardsArray.push($(this).attr('data-value'));
});

$('.goal').click(function () {
    $(".goal").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});

$("#reward-cards .card").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
    } else {
        $("#reward-cards .card").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    }
});
```

My react code is as follows:

```
var Test = React.createClass({

 btnTapped:  function(value, thisObj) {
    console.log(value);    

},
render: function() {
var stationComponents = this.props.stations.map((station, index) => {

return <div onClick={() => this. handleSort(station, $(this))}><img src="img/test.png" />{station}</div>;

   });
    return <div>{stationComponents}</div>;
   }
});

var cards = ["amazon", "aeo", "aerie", "barnes", "bloomingdales", "bbw","bestbuy", "regal", "cvs", "ebay", "gyft", "itunes", "jcp", "panera", "staples", "walmart", "target", "sephora", "walgreens", "starbucks"];

ReactDOM.render(<Test stations={cards} />, document.getElementById('test-div'));
```

Please excuse my ignorance as I'm quite new to react, but how can I replicate the jquery functionality in react? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In react you don't toggle the class by checking if the class exists on the DOM element. You change the state, and every element can react to the new state ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oadhhkc5/1/)).

I've used a trinary operator to change the class, but [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) is a better solution.

```
var cards = ["amazon", "aeo", "aerie", "barnes", "bloomingdales", "bbw", "bestbuy", "regal", "cvs", "ebay", "gyft", "itunes", "jcp", "panera", "staples", "walmart", "target", "sephora", "walgreens", "starbucks"];

var Station = React.createClass({
  btnTapped: function() {
    this.props.onStationClick(this.props.index);
  },

  render() {
    return (
        <div className={ this.props.selected ? 'selected' : '' }
        onClick ={ this.btnTapped }>
                { this.props.children }
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Test = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        selected: null
    }
  },
  onStationClick: function(index) {
    this.setState({
        selected: index
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    var stationComponents = this.props.stations.map((station, index) => (
        <Station key={ index } 
             index={ index }
           selected={ this.state.selected === index }
             onStationClick = { this.onStationClick }>
           { station }
      </Station>
    ));

    return (
        <div >{ stationComponents }</div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render( 
    <Test stations={cards} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with states also.
First take initial state as you want it to be selected or unselected

```
import React from 'react';

class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
        class : 'selected'
        // here initially it will show selected
    }

    toggleClass(){
      this.setState({class: this.state.class == 'selected' ? '' : 'selected'})
    }

    render(){
      return(
        <div>
           <div>
             <button onClick={this.toggleClass.bind(this)} type='button'></button> 
           </div>
           // Now pass state to div class that will toggle everytime user clicks.
           <div className={this.state.class}>
              // xyz data
           </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default Example;
```